# How do I prevent "comments" cell within datasheet view from populating black after exiting cell?

Tags: 2007, datasheet

A user of our SharePoint 2007 Server hosted database has been running into the issue shown within the title of this post. She is working remotely so, it is difficult for me to figure out what exactally is causing this issue. I confirmed that she is currently running IE9 as her browser for the internet. 
Are there any other questions that I should ask our remote SharePoint user about her computer or internet service that may be causing this issue?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thank You
- Jeff

Answer (score 1):

We have had success by installing this plug-in
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4438

it turns out that the default font used in the datasheet view is no longer included in the Windows7 package.